# How to combine state and continuation monads in F#

Tags: f#, state, monads, monad-transformers, continuation

I'm trying to sum a tree using the Task Parallel Library where child tasks are spawned only until the tree is traversed until a certain depth, and otherwise it sums the remaining child nodes using continuation passing style, to avoid stack overflows.

However, the code looks pretty ugly - it would be nice to use a state monad to carry the current depth around, but the state monad isn't tail recursive. Alternatively, how would I modify the continuation monad to carry around the state? Or create a combination of the state and continuation monads?

```
let sumTreeParallelDepthCont tree cont = 
  let rec sumRec tree depth cont =
    let newDepth = depth - 1
    match tree with
    | Leaf(num) -> cont num
    | Branch(left, right) ->
      if depth <= 0 then
        sumTreeContMonad left (fun leftM ->
          sumTreeContMonad right (fun rightM ->
            cont (leftM + rightM )))
      else 
        let leftTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> 
              let leftResult = ref 0
              sumRec left newDepth (fun leftM -> 
                leftResult := leftM)
              !leftResult
              )
        let rightTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> 
              let rightResult = ref 0
              sumRec right newDepth (fun rightM ->
                rightResult := rightM)
              !rightResult
              )
        cont (leftTask.Result + rightTask.Result)
  sumRec tree 4 cont // 4 levels deep
```

I've got a little more detail on this blog post: http://taumuon-jabuka.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/more-playing-with-monads.html

Comment: This is a weird combination. You're parallelizing for performance but using continuation passing style which is very inefficient.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is important to first understand what your requirements are.

- The sequential version of the algorithm does not need to keep the `depth` (because it always processes the rest of the tree). However, it needs to use continuations because the tree can be large.
- The parallel version, on the other hand, needs to keep the `depth` (because you only want to make limited number of recursive calls), but it does not need to use continuations (because the depth is quite limited and when you start a new task, it does not keep the stack anyway).

This means that you don't really need to combine the two aspects at all. Then you can rewrite the parallel version in a quite straightforward way:

```
let sumTreeParallelDepthCont tree =  
  let rec sumRec tree depth = 
    match tree with 
    | Leaf(num) -> num 
    | tree when depth <= 0 -> 
        sumTreeContMonad tree id
    | Branch(left, right) ->
        let leftTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> sumRec left (depth + 1))
        let rightResult = sumRec right (depth + 1)
        leftTask.Result + rightResult
  sumRec tree 4 // 4 levels deep
```

There is no need to duplicate the code from `sumTreeContMonad` because you can just call it on the current tree in the case `tree when depth <= 0`.

This also avoids using reference cells by creating `Task<int>` instead of `Task` and I modified the algorithm to only spawn one background task and do the second part of the work on the current thread.

Comment: This is better than my answer :)

Comment: I think the key is simplicity.  You can end up jumping down a rabbit hole searching for monadic implementations when there is an adequate an efficient solution without them.

Answer (score 2):

In my eyes, the depth looks fine, the ugly bit is the ref cells and assignments.  I am unclear why you need them; I think just passing `id` (identity function) as the `cont` parameter means that `sumRec` will return the value, and then you won't need the ref cells.  (I may be wrong, this is analysis-at-a-glance.)

(I also would get rid of `newDepth` and just inline `(depth-1)` at the recursive call sites, as a matter of style.)

Finally, I've no idea what `sumTreeContMonad` is, but it appears that you could just use `sumRec t -1 k` instead of `sumTreeContMonad t k` and it would work the same.

(If your blog had code, rather than pictures of code, I might just post my own code with these refinements, but I don't feel like transcribing the data types and such.  Why post pictures?)